# Creating a list containing a string from another list [Edited]

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am trying to create a list from another list, such as:

```
List<String> namesOfLotion = List.of("Alexander Almond & Honey Moisturiser", "Max honey and almond moisturiser", "Mikhail Almond and Talc", "Mikhail Natural Almond Moisturizer", "Tigran Aloe Isolani", "Vassily Aloe Attack", "Vassily New aloe Attack");
```

From there I want to get all the names, which contains 'Aloe'

for which I am using following logic:

```
List<String> aloeLotion = trendyList.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.trim().equals("Aloe"));
```

But it returns me Boolean values rather than names.
How Can I achieve that.

I want to carried out name of elements which contains 'Aloe', such as :

```
List.of("Tigran Aloe Isolani", "Vassily Aloe Attack", "Vassily New aloe Attack");
```

But I need to know, if it has with both ['aloe', 'Aloe'], what will be the case?

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) instead of [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))

Comment: Can you update that first snippet to be real code?

Answer (score 2):

First you should use 'filter' and not 'anyMatch'

```
List<String> aloeLotion = trendyList.stream().filter(str -> str.trim().equals("Aloe"));
```

Also, You asked for contained 'Aloe' so you should use 'contains' and not 'equals' and also remove the 'trim'

```
List<String> aloeLotion = trendyList.stream().filter(str -> str.contains("Aloe"));
```

Finally, since filter is not a stream-terminating function, you should collect the results to list

```
List<String> aloeLotion = trendyList.stream().filter(str -> str.contains("Aloe")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thats really awesome @Yogev, I need to know, what if we have a List of strings i.e. ['Aloe' , 'aloe'], then?

Comment: you can use 'uppercase' to make the string upper and use contains with 'ALOE'. or use matches intead with regex which ignores case.